# Объект не добавляется к списку

Tags: python, ооп

Есть 2 класса: Smartphone и review (смартфон может иметь много отзывов).
Пытаюсь добавить review методом `append` в конец списка, и не получаю ничего.

```
class Smartphone:
    reviews = []

    def __init__(self, imageURL, url, name, brand, rating, specifications, expSpecifications):
        self.imageURL = imageURL
        self.url = url
        self.name = name
        self.brand = brand
        self.rating = rating
        self.specifications = specifications
        self.expSpecifications = expSpecifications

    def addReview(self, singleReview):
        self.reviews.append(singleReview)

    def printReviews(self):
        i = 0
        if len(self.reviews) > 0:
            while i < len(self.reviews):
                print(self.reviews)
                i += 1
        else:
            return


class review:
    def __init__(self, rating, author, date, commentary, usefulCount):
        self.rating = rating
        self.author = author
        self.date = date
        self.commentary = commentary
        self.usefulCount = usefulCount

    def printReview(self):
        print(self.rating)
        print(self.date)
        print(self.author)
        print(self.commentary)
        print(self.usefulCount)
```

Main:

```
class Main:
    @staticmethod
    def main():
        pass

    firstTry = review(5, "gay", "19022019", "only 4 gays", "1355 of 2000")
    samsungGalaxy10 = Smartphone("http:image.png", "http:smartphonePage.com", "A10", "Samsung", "5", "techicalCharacteristics", "extendedTC")
    samsungGalaxy10.addReview(firstTry)
    samsungGalaxy10.printReviews()
```

Показывает пустой список. Однако, когда вручную заполняешь список reviews = ["dd", "tt"] и т.п., то все прекрасно показывается.

Comment: У меня ваш код работает. Печатает список из одного элемента `[<__main__.review object at 0x0000000002A47D08>]`. Если у этого элемента вызвать `printReview()`, то печатает содержимое полей.

Comment: попробуйте заполнить список вручную, посмотрите как должно выглядеть

Comment: Не понимаю почему не используете метод класса для вывода `self.reviews[i].printReview()`

Comment: Что значит вручную? Он и выглядит нормально, вы же в него экземпляр класса добавляете, а не текст.

Comment: @GrAnd моя задача вывести список Review в методе printReview из класса Smartphone. Но почему-то review не попадает в список класса Смартфон

Comment: Ваш метод для печати должен быть просто таким:  `def printReviews(self):
        for review in self.reviews:
            review.printReview()`.

Comment: @GrAnd действительно, завтыкал. Вы помогли, спасибо